# Angular 1.5, Calling a function in a component from Parent controller

Tags: angularjs

Angular 1.5 components easily allow creating a call back to the parent from the component. Is there a way i can call a function in a component from a function in parent's controller ?

Lets say my component is called task-runner and below is the HTML for it in the parent container.

```
<task-runner taskcategogyid=5></task-runner>

 <button type="button" ng-click="doSomethingInParent()">ParentToChildButton</button>
```

The plunkr is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CtQ33KabRgQYKha1hr7m?p=preview). I want that when ParentToChildButton is clicked, the function doSomethingInParent() calls the remotefunc in component.

Comment: Please add component definition.

Comment: Components = https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: No I meant your code, for your component. Not the definition of what a component is. The actual JS part.

Answer (score 21):

A few different ways:

1. Pass an object as an attribute with two-way binding (`scope:{myattr:'='}`) to the task-item-header directive which the directive could then add a function to for the parent controller to call.
2. Set an attribute that has either one-way binding (`scope:{myattr:'@'}`) on it and then `attrs.$observe` changes to it to trigger the action, or two-way binding (`scope:{myattr:'='}`) and then `$scope.$watch` changes to it to trigger the action.
3. Have the directive raise an event (`scope:{raiseLoaded:'&onLoaded'}`) that passes an object that represents a remote control object with a method on it that triggers the action you want. To raise the event, you'd call something like `raiseLoaded({remoteControl: remoteControlObj})` within the directive, and then to listen to the event, you'd use `<task-item-header on-loaded="setRemote(remoteControl)">` assuming you have a `setRemote()` method on your parent controller.

**Update** I just realized your question was for a newer version of AngularJS, so I'm not sure if my answer still applies. I'll leave it here for now, but if you find it is not helpful I can delete it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on #3 ? Its not clear to me which property is set  in the parent (component container) and which property is set in the component ? I have added a plunkr to my original post. I want that when i click parenttochildbutton the remotefunc() in component is called with alert(5)

Comment: You can delete it as it can cause people to think its already answered.

Comment: @TkNeo, I modified your plunkr to do as I describe in #3: http://plnkr.co/edit/vRVZB9EhhZd4sYTGoPvC?p=info

Answer (score 19):

I needed something like this previously so I thought I would share how I solved this problem.

Similar to the OP, I needed to **freely** trigger methods in child components from a parent component. I wanted to be able to trigger this method in the parent freely/separately without the use of the $onChanges lifecycle hook.

Instead I created a notification-registration mechanism to allow a child component to 'register' a method with the parent when it is loaded. This method can then be freely triggered by the parent outside of the $onChanges cycle.

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/rdrwoodall/pen/ZvvrEy) to demonstrate this. It can be easily extended to handle different types of notifications from the parent that aren't related to the data changes.

**Index.html**

```
<div ng-app="tester">
  <parent></parent>
</div>
```

**Script.js**

```
angular.module('tester', []);

angular.module('tester').component('parent', {
  controller: parentController,
  template: `
    <div class="tester-style">
      <button ng-click="$ctrl.notifyChild()">Notify child</button>
      <child parent-to-child-notification-registration="$ctrl.childComponentNotificationRegistration(handler)">
    </div>
  `
});

function parentController() {
  let childComponentEventHandler = null;

  this.$onInit = function() {
    this.value = 0;
  };

  this.childComponentNotificationRegistration = function(handler) {
    childComponentEventHandler = handler;
    console.log('Child component registered.');
  };

  this.notifyChild = function() {
    if (childComponentEventHandler) {
      childComponentEventHandler(this.value++);
    }
  };
}

angular.module('tester').component('child', {
  bindings: {
    parentToChildNotificationRegistration: '&',
  },
  controller: childController,
  template: `
    <div class="tester-style">
      <h4>Child Component</h4>
    </div>
  `
});

function childController() {
  this.$onInit = function() {
    this.parentToChildNotificationRegistration({
      handler: this.processParentNotification
    });
  };

  this.processParentNotification= function(parentValue) {
    console.log('Parent triggered child notification handler!!!');
    console.log('Value passed to handler:', parentValue);
  };
};
```

}

Also for something similar to [@adam0101](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64279/adam0101)'s #3 answer see [codepen](https://codepen.io/rdrwoodall/pen/jYYGKG).

Comment: Regarding this answer, one may simplify by claiming `ctrl.onXxEvt = {}` in the parent controller; then claiming `onXxEvt="$ctrl.onXxEvt"` at the child-component anchor in the parent template; and then claiming in the child's controller's `$onInit` that `ctrl.onXxEvt.handler = xxEvtHander`. Now you can call `ctrl.onXxEvt.handler` in the parent controller, which will invoke `xxEvtHander` in the child controller. This avoides the explicit registration method.

Comment: Thank you! Such a clever solution. Cheers