# Angular 1.5. | invoke a function from parent component clicking on child component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app with angular 1.5 there are two components. A parent one:

```
angular.
module('myApp').
component('myContainer', {
    bindings: {
        saySomething: '&'
    },
    controller: ['$scope', function MyController($scope) {
        var containerCtrl = this;
        containerCtrl.saySomething = function saySomething() {
            containerCtrl.sentence = "Hello, world";
            console.log(containerCtrl.sentence);
        };
    }]
});
```

And a child one:

```
angular.
module('myApp').
component('myButton', {
    bindings: {
        onClick: '&'
    },
    template:
    '<div>' +
        '<a class="button" href="#">Say Something</a>' +
    '</div>'
});
```

And here is my index.html:

```
<my-container>
    <my-button ng-click="$ctrl.saySomething()"></my-button>
</my-container>
```

The question is: how to invoke the function saySomething() from the parent component by clicking on the button in the child component? Now it doesn't work. I've seen a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215547/angular-1-5-calling-a-function-in-a-component-from-parent-controller) but this didn't solve my problem.
Thanks in advance for the help!

P.S. If there are any similar questions, please, let me know. Tnanks!

Comment: generally this approach doesnt work. what you can do is pass a binding variable and do a watch (or onchange) and then fire the function

Comment: @elasticrash, thank you for your answer, but could you give an example? Or maybe a link to an example?

Comment: you can require parent controller in child component and then redirect the call from child to parent

Comment: @Aleksey L., thank you for your answer, but what do you mean by "redirect the call from child to parent"? How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `require` parent controller in child component and then invoke its methods.

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .component('myContainer', {
    ...
  })
  .component('myButton', {
    require: {
      parentCtrl: '^myContainer'
    },
    template: '<div>' +
      '<a class="button" href="#" ng-click="$ctrl.parentCtrl.saySomething()">Say Something</a>' +
      '</div>'
  });
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwu6j825/)

And link to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication)

Comment: You don't need to require anything, you can just pass the method into the child component using a method binding

Comment: @MichaelWestcott that's just another option. Also if you need to access more than one parent's member/function 'require' is much more handy. Another thing to take into account is when using method binding to invoke method with parameters - syntax is slightly different.

Comment: @AlekseyL. Completely agree, I was just referring to the question asked as in that situation a method binding might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

the thing is though that it only works for one way binded values

```
   mod.component('myCmp', {
      template: '<h1>{{$ctrl.name}}</h1>',
      bindings: {
        name: '<'
      },
      controller:  {
      this.$onChanges = function (changesObj) {
        if (changesObj.name) {
         ...fire some function
        }
      };
    }
    });
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but should I put this code into my parent or child component?

Comment: this is for the only way a parent can call a function that exists on the child so it goes on the child. If you want the child to call a parent function then you need to add a require on the parent and get immediate access

Answer (score -1):

I'm late to the party but i think there's a better way to handle that, here's a small example:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.component('reportPrintButton', {
        template: [
            '<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="$ctrl.onClick()">',
                '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> {{ $ctrl.name }}',
            '</button>'
        ].join(''),
        bindings: {
            name: '@',
            onClick: '&'
        },
        controller: reportPrintButton
    });

    reportPrintButton.$inject = [];

    function reportPrintButton() {
        var ctrl = this;
    }
})();

// On view use it like this where in the on-click attribute use the function
// you want to trigger from parent component
<report-print-button name="Complete" on-click="printReport('Complete')">
</report-print-button>
```

Comment: how does this answers the question?

Comment: Usage in view:

`<report-print-button name="Complete" on-click="printReport('Complete')"></report-print-button>`


When the user clicks on the button rendered from the component, it will trigger a callback which will call the function inside the on-click from parent Component.